# Как узнать формат преобразования даты в SQL запросе, используемый по умолчанию?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql-developer

В каких-то СУБД (или только в среде, не уверен) по умолчанию используется один формат даты, в каких-то - другой. Например:

```
select * from subs_histories where start_date >'01-NOV-01'
```

Где-то выполнится корректно, а где-то не распознает дату в строке.

Как понять какой формат даты используется по умолчанию, не приводя явно к типу даты?

Comment: `select * from subs_histories where start_date > '2001-11-01` выполнится всегда и везде

Comment: @AntonShchyrov "ORA-01861: литерал не соответствует формату строки"

Comment: Кавычку в конце не забыли?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не забыл :) Без неё было бы "ORA-01756: нет завершающей кавычки"

Comment: `date` забыли перед датой :) См. мой ответ.

Comment: Кстати, во многих средах (даже в SQLPlus!) можно настроить автоматическое выполнение скриптов при коннекте. А в них уже прописывать любые форматы, и вообще много всего полезного.

Comment: @Dmitry Не забыл. Не знал. С ораклом только начинаю знакомиться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При такой форме записи:

```
... where start_date > '01-NOV-01'
```

произойдёт неявное преобразование даты в соответствии с форматом указанным в `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` для текущей сессии, узнать который можно так:

```
SQL> select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

PARAMETER         VALUE
----------------- -------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT   DD-MON-RR
```

То есть, по сути будет выполнено:

```
... where start_date > to_date ('01-NOV-01', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

Практически невозможно добится установки одного и того же значения по умолчанию параметра `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` для всех сессий, где выполняется запрос с подобной формой записи.
Поэтому, форму записи без явного указания формата преобразования даты, или как упомянуто в вопросе:

> не приводя явно к типу даты

**не рекомендуется использовать и следует избегать**.

Надо либо явно указывать формат даты, как в вашем случае:

```
to_date ('01-ЯНВ-01', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

Либо задавать литерал даты (date literal) в формате ANSI `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

```
... where start_date > date'2001-11-01'
```

Этот формат не зависит от NLS настроек сессии или базы данных и не может быть изменён. Подобная форма записи является предпочтительной, если не надо указывать время, т.к. оно в этом формате отсутствует.

Подробнее в [офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062).

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что не стоит этим пользоваться и никогда не воспользуюсь. Просто в учебном материале от оракла был код, который у меня не запустился. Мне стало любопытно.

Comment: Может в учебном материале на этом месте как раз и шла речь о неявном преобразовании. Если нет, то надо выбррать другой в учебный материал.

Comment: Ну, официальный вродь как оракловый для подготовке к экзамену их же.

Answer (score 4):

За региональные настройки формата даты, времени, чисел и прочего отвечают параметры, которые можно посмотреть в `V$NLS_PARAMETERS`:

```
select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS
```

Конкретно за дату - параметр `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. Установить его можно так, например:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
```

И проверить:

```
select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE           
-------------------
01.03.2018 16:02:10
```

Кроме того, ISO формат даты `YYYY-MM-DD` принимается всегда и при любых настройках:

```
select sysdate from dual 
 where date '2018-01-01' < sysdate;

SYSDATE           
-------------------
01.03.2018 16:05:15
```

P. S. Есть еще хитрый параметр `NLS_TERRITORY`, от него зависит, какой день недели будет первым. У американцев это воскресенье, у европейцев - понедельник.

Comment: Да,  > date '2001-11-01' работает, но что касается параметра, но в таблице NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR, а >'01-NOV-01' всё-равно не работает ._. и > date '01-JAN-01' тоже не работает.

Comment: разобрался почему не хочет. Важен еще параметр NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE. У меня он стоял русский, поэтому дату просил '01-ЯНВ-01'

Comment: Немного перепутал. Ключевое слово `date` требует всегда формата 'YYYY-MM-DD' ([дока](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)), а настройка `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` позволяет, кроме всего прочего, писать `to_date('<какой-нибудь формат>')` без точного указания формата. Ну и там еще куча всяких тонкостей, связанных с тем, что если вы пропустите некоторые символы в текстовом представлении даты, оракл все равно поймет